# Почему переменная из цикла в JTextField не отображается?

Tags: java, gui

уважаемые знатоки! Есть класс Scan с потоком, в котором работает цикл. В цикле вычисляется некая переменная String x. И нужно ее вставить в JTextField в классе Panel. Посредством setJTextField(x) почему-то не получается. В поле ничего не меняется. Если кому не сложно объясните почему так и что нужно изменить?

Класс Main (на всякий случай):

```
   package formfactor;

import formfactor.Scan;
import formfactor.Scan.ScanFile1;
public class FormFactor {

   
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.setVisible(true);
      ScanFile sf = new ScanFile();
      formfactor.Scan scan = new formfactor.Scan();
     Scan.ScanFile1 search = scan.new ScanFile1(panel);
        sf.start();
        search.start();
         Variables variables = new Variables();
       
      
    }
    
}
```

Класс Scan:

```
package formfactor;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import formfactor.Variables;

public class Scan {


 
    

public class ScanFile1 extends Thread{

     String result1="00";
     Panel pan;
     public ScanFile1(Panel pan) {
         
         this.pan = pan;}
     
public void setResult1(String result1) {
        this.result1 = result1;}
        
 public String getResult(){return result1;}
    
       
   
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            try{
                             
                sleep(5000);        
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
                      
                        
            System.out.println("CUCAN!");   
                        
                        
                        try
{
BufferedReader iu = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("lala.txt"));
String ki;
ki = iu.readLine();
iu.close();
                           String x = ki;
                           setResult1(x); 
                          
System.out.println("x=" + x);
System.out.println("result = "+result1);
setResult1(x);
Variables v = new Variables();                 
v.setLs(x);                                    
System.out.println(v.getLs()+ " This is");     



pan.setJTextField(x);



}
catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
{
                            
                            String x = "0";
}       catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FormFactor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
                        
                        
                 
                        
                        
        }
            
    }
 
}



    
}
```

Класс Panel:

```
package formfactor;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Noutbook
 */
public class Panel extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    /**
     * Creates new form Panel
     */
    public Panel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public JTextField getjTextField1() {
        return jTextField1;
    }

    public void setjTextField1(String text) {this.JTextField1 = JTextField1
       
    }
    
   
    
    public void setJTextField(String text){this.JTextField = JTextField}
    
    public JTextField getjTextField1(String text) {
        return jTextField1;
    }


    public Panel(JTextField jTextField1) {
        this.jTextField1 = jTextField1;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.setText("Text");

        jButton2.setText("EXIT");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 222, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 75, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 220, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
System.exit(0);        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Panel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Panel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Panel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Panel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Panel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы в новый Panel параметры передаете,а не в тот который у вас создан.

```
Panel Pan = new Panel();
Pan.setJTextField(x);
```

Зачем вам вообще вложенный класс ?

```
public class ScanFile1 extends Thread{

 String result1="00";
 Panel pan;
 // Добавьте поле класса Panel 
 // Передав ему ссылку через конструктор
 
 public ScanFile1(Panel pan){
  this.pan = pan;
 }
//.... Ваш код далее
```

Теперь передайте Panel классу ScanFile1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Panel panel = new Panel();
  panel.setVisible(true);
  ScanFile sf = new ScanFile();
  formfactor.Scan scan = new formfactor.Scan();
  Scan.ScanFile1 search = scan.new ScanFile1(panel); // here
  sf.start();
  search.start();
  Variables variables = new Variables(); 
}
```

Удалите корень проблемы

```
 //.. Code

 Panel Pan = new Panel(); // delete 
 pan.setJTextField(x); 

 // .. Code
```

А ещё ваш код очень сложно читать, режет глаза простите за откровенность, хотя бы пробегитесь глазами по java convention....

Comment: Искренне благодарю за Вашу помощь и критику (я ее приветствую). Переделал все так, как вы описали. Но по-прежнему не появляется в JTextField значение переменной "x". Не могу понять почему. А Java convention обязательно изучу досконально.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, благодаря максимально развернутому ответу господина Perfect Voyage разобрался в этом, пока еще непростом для меня вопросе.